# Textviews alignment in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I'm attempting to create a simple layout which will contain an imageview (it will be centered in the layout) and 3 textviews (which will centered but aligned to the left of the imageview). Currently I accomplished to create the layout as I wanted except for the alignment of the textviews (they are basically centered to the layout rather being aligned to the left). I tried to remove the constraint

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

It didn't helped and created a new issue which is creating too big space between the imageview and the textviews.

This is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item 1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Production date:"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Item price"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is will make the following layout
[image: output]

Comment: do you want the text on the right of the image or on the left?

Comment: On the right side of the imageview, can all of the texviews could be centered vertically to the imageview instead of the parent?

Comment: I have an answer below, but I'm not really sure if you want the imageview centred both vertically and horizontally. Let me know, and I'll adjust it to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to centre all views vertically, and have the text on the right of the imageview. If so, try this:

**EDIT - added new layout based on your comment**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Item 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Production date:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Item price"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview2" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you centered all the textviews vertically between the imageview?

Comment: @AntonMakov try it now